# This is what I want to do. I want to link them together

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, .net-core

```
enter code here
public class Product //Join table
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Productcode { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ProductMovement> ProductMovements { get; set; }  //Master Table
}


public class ProductMovement   //Master Table
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Productcode { get; set; }

    public string Aciklama  { get; set; }

    public virtual Product Product { get; set; } //join tablo

}
enter code here
```

I want to join using this field.  **public string Productcode { get; set;** }

How can I do this with an entity?

Comment: What do you mean by join?  Do you need just a query with 2 tables  or you want to create  relations between these tables?

Comment: I want to create a relationship...

Comment: What kind of relationship? One-to-many, many-to-many and between which tables? Anyway try adding `ProductId` or `ProductMovementId` depending on which kind of relationship you want to add.
Also consider removing `ProductCode` from `ProductMovement` as you can receive this info by joining tables